# What settings should I add to send external data to Graylog?

Tags: mongodb, docker, elasticsearch, graylog

When I run the graylog web service on localhost, I get it at 127.0.0.1:9000. I installed Docker on a server.
GRAYLOG_HTTP_EXTERNAL_URI
GRAYLOG_HTTP_BIND_ADDRESS
GRAYLOG_HTTP_PUBLISH_URI

I wrote the ip addresses, but graylog works in server local. What do I need to do to send data from Graylog outside?

```
version: '3'
services:
# MongoDB: https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/
  mongo:
    image: mongo:5.0.13
    networks:
      - graylog
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/docker/volumes/mongo:/data/db
    
  # Elasticsearch: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/docker.html
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:7.10.2
    environment:
      - http.host=0.0.0.0
      - transport.host=localhost
      - network.host=0.0.0.0
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 1.5G
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/docker/volumes/elk:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
    - graylog
  # Graylog: https://hub.docker.com/r/graylog/graylog/
  graylog:
    image: graylog/graylog:5.0
    environment:
    - TZ=Europe/Istanbul
    # CHANGE ME (must be at least 16 characters)!
    - GRAYLOG_PASSWORD_SECRET=908bd4dee1
    - Password=Y71
    - GRAYLOG_ROOT_PASSWORD_SHA2=8c6976e5b541
    - GRAYLOG_HTTP_EXTERNAL_URI=http://10.90.104.143:9000/ #example ip
    - GRAYLOG_HTTP_BIND_ADDRESS=10.90.104.143:9000 #example ip
    - GRAYLOG_HTTP_PUBLISH_URI=http://10.90.104.143:9000/ #example ip
    #- GRAYLOG_TRAGRAYLOG_TRANSPORT_EMAIL_ENABLED: "true"
    #- GRAYLOG_TRANSPORT_EMAIL_HOSTNAME: smtp
    #- GRAYLOG_TRANSPORT_EMAIL_PORT: 25
    #- GRAYLOG_TRANSPORT_EMAIL_USE_AUTH: "false"
    #- GRAYLOG_TRANSPORT_EMAIL_USE_TLS: "false"
    #- GRAYLOG_TRANSPORT_EMAIL_USE_SSL: "false"


    volumes:
      - graylog_data:/usr/share/graylog/data
      - graylog_journal:/usr/share/graylog/journal

    networks:
    - graylog
    restart: always
    depends_on:
    - mongo
    - elasticsearch
    ports:
    # Graylog web interface and REST API
      - 9000:9000
      # Syslog TCP
      - 1514:1514
      # Syslog UDP
      - 1514:1514/udp
      # GELF TCP
      - 12201:12201
      # GELF UDP
      - 12201:12201/udp
networks:
  graylog:
    driver: bridge
    
volumes:
  graylog_data:
  graylog_journal:
```

What settings should I add to send external data to Graylog?